# Regex to remove 'groups of characters' with less than 3 characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove any 'groups of characters' with less than 3 characters.

This is the source:

> 1.29 Cancels part plan C/5879 2030. in i i.r e9g6Pop Iatian Area ProcH 22.4.93 Suburban Lands n f 53dv 3 N014 3.5.98. PLAN or any from 01 53 under M R.5I B.L.1laY98 E35. P0 RT I 0 N S At Maroubrajuncti p /I .z. .0 / .L .I. .I

Settings bounds for word characters with repetition between 1 and 3 e.g. /b\w{1,3}\b/ does not work as "C/5879" would become "5879".

The desired output would be as follows:

> 1.29 Cancels part plan C/5879 2030. e9g6Pop Iatian Area ProcH 22.4.93 Suburban Lands 53dv N014 3.5.98. PLAN from under R.5I B.L.1laY98 E35. Maroubrajuncti

An alternative which could also work would be to create larger 'groups of characters' by joining 'groups of characters' with 2 or less characters delimited by a whitespace.

For example:

> 1.29 Cancels part plan C/5879 2030. inii.r e9g6Pop Iatian Area ProcH 22.4.93 Suburban Lands nf 53dv 3N014 3.5.98. PLAN orany from 0153 under MR.5I B.L.1laY98 E35. P0RTI0NS AtMaroubrajuncti p/I.z. .0/.L.I..I

I would be open to either solution to rescue me from Regex Hell.

Comment: Regexes don't remove things, they match things! What language are you using? That determines the regex flavor and the rest of the toolset available.

Comment: True. I should have said a regex to match 3 or less sequential characters delimited by whitespace. I am using with PHP's preg_replace to 'remove' aka replace with ''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of "words" is "whitespace delimited", which differ from regex's defitionition of "word to non-word", so use look arounds:

```
\s+\S{1,3}(?=\s)
```

Note that the expression *includes* (captures) leading spaces, so removing matches will not leave double spaces in the result.

When tested on regextester result is:

> 1.29 Cancels part plan C/5879 2030. e9g6Pop Iatian Area ProcH 22.4.93 Suburban Lands 53dv N014 3.5.98. PLAN from under R.5I B.L.1laY98 E35. Maroubrajuncti .I

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian .. I am using with PHP's preg_replace. Unfortunately this removes too many characters either side of the 'grouping'.  
Here is the output:  
  
`1    Canc  p  p  C/5  20     e9g6   Iat  A  Pr   22.4    Subur  La    5   N  3.5.     P               f    un   R    B.L.1la  E         Maroubrajun`

Comment: Oops - changed * to + fixed it. Try it now.

Comment: perfect! Thank you. Do you want to have a go at the other regex i.e. match for 2 or less than chars delimited by whitespace for replace with '' to make larger garbled words as a separate Answer to award you twice. Cheers.